# Creating an editable editor in TinyMCE 3 without it taking focus

Tags: javascript, tinymce

The code I'm working on creates 3 input editors in a form, using this : `tinymce.init(config)`.

The problem is that the three inputs take focus while the for is generated, making it scroll several times.

One of the solutions I pursued was to set `readonly` to true in the config, and then make the editor editable (called the "design" mode) afterwards. The trouble is, the `setMode` method doesn't work immediately after the init function is called. So I tried to circumvent it the following way :

```js
const editor = tinymce.get(config.elements);

editor.on('init', function () {
    editor.setMode("design");
});
```

The good news is that it doesn't set the focus. The bad news is that it's unreliable, usually the editor stays disabled.

Is there a reliable way of creating non-readonly editors, without them taking focus, in TinyMCE 3.4.7 ?